# Find Map and Layer ID in Google Maps Engine

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-engine

I want to add a map from Maps Engine to a page but I can't figure out how to get the Map ID or Layer ID required for the MapsEngineLayer.

It seems like they forgot to add this to the new interface.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mapsenginelayers) seems to give directions that do not apply for the new interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was also confusing for me, there is

- [Maps Engine Lite](https://mapsengine.google.com/map/)
- [Maps Engine Pro](http://www.google.com/enterprise/mapsearth/)
- [Maps Engine](http://mapsengine.google.com/admin/)

The linked documentation is related to [Maps Engine](http://www.google.com/enterprise/mapsearth/products/mapsengine.html).

Maps created via Maps Engine Lite/Pro may only be embedded or shared via link.

Comment: You have got to be kidding me! That is terrible design

Comment: yeah! What the heck is going on here??  Especially since Maps Engine appears to be much harder to use.

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about Google Maps Engine, you can find the MAP ID, LAYER ID when you are on a layer (or map) using the Google Maps Engine console Admin => top left : Access link.  Click on it, and next you'll have the asset id.

[image: Here is the "menu"]

Hope this help you.
Sebastien

Comment: Wow why do they add a button with no caption that opens up a popup that gives only 1 data when they could have only put the data directly in the page? Silly Google designers...

Comment: where can I find this ?